# Should I send a file over sockets in one read\write or multiple chunks?

Tags: c++, sockets, ftp

I have a basic question regarding how to implement a basic file transfer client\server in c++.

I am not sure why it is not a good way to send file in one read\write and why the good way is sending it in chunks of small buffer?

Answer (score 5):

> I am not sure why it is not a good way to send file in one read\write and why the good way is sending it in chunks of small buffer?

If you have a file with a size of 2TB it you would first need to allocate this amount of RAM and load the whole file into this single buffer. Then you need to write out all of this buffer. This will probably not succeed with a 2TB file anyway because of out of memory but even for smaller files this would be a waste of resources. Since the reads from the disk and the writes to the network card are internally done in chunks anyway you would not get better performance even if the whole file fits into RAM.

A could compromise might be to read/write in chunks of something between 4k and 32k, optimal size depends on OS, disk buffer, socket buffer, speed of disk and network etc.

Comment: Thanks! Do you recommend reading using functions like open & pread or simpler functions fstream and etc ?

Comment: fstream introduces additional buffering and overhead, so read/readv/pread are better if you can do an optimal buffer management yourself. If you want to just transfer from file to network sendfile might be even better because you don't have to copy the data between kernel and user space.

Comment: Well, you *can* write a huge file in one chunk without needing the corresponding memory: Just `mmap()` the file, then call `write()` for the whole thing. The kernel will figure out the rest.

Comment: @cmaster Assuming your kernel can memory-map terabytes. Not a recommendable technique.

Comment: @EJP Should be no problem on a 64 bit system. After all, the kernel never has to actually load the entire file at once, or even try to do so. It can simply reuse the memory pages that contain file data since it knows that it can reload this data from disk, no need to actually swap out anything. Nevertheless, I haven't tried this for lack of a 2TB file, but I know that it works for files larger than main memory. Of course, using a zero copy syscall like `sendfile()` is probably the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an IP based protocol to send this file you are anyhow limited to the packet size of IP which is around 64K.

If you use UDP, then your transfer is not reliable but then it also better to limit the packet size to around 450 bytes to avoid that parts of the packet are lost. You would also have to device some kind of sequence number in each send to detect that such a chunk gets lost, and perhaps an acking mechanism. TFTP has such a mechanism already in place.

If you use TCP, which is reliable, then you don't have to chop in 450 bytes, you can use 32000 bytes or even 64K (not a limit of TCP but you avoid needing a large chunk of memory, reading and sending in blocks of 32k is perfectly reasonable). TCP is going to send according to the Mtu. So be prepared that on the receiving side you will not receive packets of 32000.

For performance reasons you want your disk access to be 'bigger chunks'. Reading and sending byte per byte will probably work but will be terribly slow.

Comment: You're not limited by the packet size of IP. TCP will take care of all required packetization. You can write in as bg chunks as you like. However chunks larger than your own socket send buffer are pretty pointless, as is trying to load the entire file into memory before sending.

Comment: As you can read in my statement TCP is going to send according to the MTU. We already established that it is not wise to load 1TB in memory and try to send that. Reading blocks of say 32k or 64k will very likely yield similar results. So there is no point in using bigger chunks.